# NSFetchedResultsController ignoring fetchLimit after update/deletion

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am creating a todo list with CollectionView(VC1) and FRC.

I am first displaying *VC1 on my homepage*(in a section of another CVC) with a limit of items set to 3(Like a preview). Then I have a button which presents *VC1 fullscreen* and displays the entire count of items.

So far fetch limit is working correctly. However when I am on *VC1 fullscreen* I can update/delete items, now when I perform collectionView.performBatchUpdates I delete/update items and both instances of the views and updated accordingly. But...

If I add 3 more items, *VC1 on the home page*: limit is not 3 anymore but 6.

If I delete 2 items, *VC1 on the home page*: is now only displaying 1 item even if in coreData I have another 20.

It seems that no matter what the limit is set to, how many ever I delete or insert the collectionView updates accordingly. Now should I recall fetch items every time?

Here is some code of how I set the limits and update collectionView

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<TodoItem> = {

        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request: NSFetchRequest<TodoItem> = TodoItem.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        ]

    request.fetchLimit = mode == .fullscreen ? .max : 3

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        frc.delegate = self

        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }

        return frc
    }()

// Number of items in CV
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let allItems = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    let numberOfRows = mode == .fullscreen ? allItems : min(allItems, 3)
    return numberOfRows
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    itemChanges.append((type, indexPath, newIndexPath))
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

    collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({

        for change in self.itemChanges {
            switch change.type {
            case .insert:

                self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [change.newIndexPath!])
            case .delete:

                self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [change.indexPath!])
            case .update:

                self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [change.indexPath!])
            case .move:

                self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [change.indexPath!])
                self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [change.newIndexPath!])
            @unknown default:
                return
            }
        }
    }, completion: { finished in
        self.itemChanges.removeAll()
    })
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The closure of the lazy instantiated variable is executed only **once**.

You have to change the fetch request with appropriate fetch limit somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I thought of that but not sure how I could set that again in didChange. I tried controller.fetchRequest.fetchLimit again in that function however that did nothing. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: After changing the request you have to refetch the data.

Comment: Also because I set the limit, when I delete an item greater than index 3 the CVC crashes on VC1... Which is expected with the current code setup but not desired of course!

Comment: Ok, and do you think that is "good" if I perform a new request every time a new item is deleted/added? or should I maybe not use the same VC on both home screen and view all screen? and then update VC1 every time it appears with a limit of 3? this might be getting slightly confusing, I apologise

Comment: It is obviously trying to have this preview of 3 items on the home page which is causing the whole issue

Comment: I would use the FRC only for the *total* view and maintain the preview manually or with diffable data source,

Comment: Yes, I think that may be a better solution... Just use a normal CVC for the preview. only issue is figuring how to update the preview if the FRC is updated.

Comment: Subscribe to contextDidSave notification and refetch the data

Comment: That said adding the following:           controller.fetchRequest.fetchLimit = mode == .fullscreen ? .max : 2 ; try? controller.performFetch()          kind of fixed the issue, but I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.

I think this is the reason : [NSFetchedResultsController ignores fetchLimit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858228/nsfetchedresultscontroller-ignores-fetchlimit)

Maybe using `fetchBatchSize` is a better substitution of `fetchLimit`, if you goal is simply to minimize memory consumption of your app. Please note that, `fetchBatchSize` and `fetchLimit` are having different behaviors, even though they might be helpful in optimizing memory consumption.